# How to replace jcarousel slider html using ajax call in php MVC framework

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have two jcarousel slider in my php web application, one is for selecting month and another is for dates related to that month, i want to do it using jquery ajax,
 whatever the month i am selecting all the dates should be coming in second slider, is there any way please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First setup the month and dates basic html.

```
<ul id="months" class="jcarousel-skin">
    <li>Jan</li>
    <li>Feb</li>
    <li>Mar</li>
    <li>Apr</li>
    <li>May</li>
    <li>Jun</li>
    <li>Jul</li>
    <li>Aug</li>
    <li>Sep</li>
    <li>Oct</li>
    <li>Nov</li>
    <li>Dec</li>
</ul>

<ul id="dates" class="jcarousel-skin">

</ul>
```

Now in javascript setup the months' carousel and dates ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#months').jcarousel();

    // Assuming you are going to load months' dates onclick
    $('#months > li').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'your-server-script.php?month=' . $(this).text(),
            success : function(data){
                /* Return the dates as html in li tags from server
                    <li>1, Friday</li><li>2, Saturday</li> .... <li>30, whatever</li>
                   and put in the dates ul.
                   You can also pass json(or any other format) and create the html here and put it in.
                */
                $('#dates').html(data);

                // Now setup the dates carousel.
                $('#dates').jcarousel();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Hope this helps. If you have more questions, paste along with the html.

Comment: below is my javascript code

            $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url : url,
         dataType: "html",
         data: "month="+monthCount.i,
         success: function(data){ 
           $('#datas-content-week-days').html(data);
           $('#datas-content-week-days').jcarousel();
                }, 
         error: function(error){
              console.log("Error:");
              console.log(error);
         }
     });   

after using ajax call code my dates jcarousel slider is not sliding properly, before ajax call it is sliding properly. please help in this ..

Comment: hmm.., it seems to work. please set it up in http://jsfiddle.net/, share the link.